# Plotting colours by array index with pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to use pcolormesh to plot data with the jet colormap. I want to control the colour stretch by breaking the data spread into intervals and assign a colour to each interval. Then I want the last interval (anything above "redvalue", usually 30) to be plotted with red.

In Matlab I use as many data intervals as there are elements in the colour map. The last interval is assigned the colour in the last element of the colour array (the "most shiny" red).

```
range = redvalue - datamin;
colours  = colormap('hsv');
count = max(size(colours));
localrange = range/count;
localmin = datamin-localrange;
localmax = datamin;

% Plot the first n - 1 number of intervals
for j = 1 : count - 1
    localmin = localmin + localrange;
    localmax = localmax + localrange;
    ind = find(data >= localmin & data < localmax)
    p = plot3(x(ind),y(ind),data(ind), '.', 'Color', colours(j,:), 'MarkerSize', 5, 'MarkerFaceColor', colours(j,:));
end

%% Now plot the final colour to points >= 30
ind = find( data >= redvalue ); % make these points red
p = plot3(x(ind),y(ind),data(ind), '.', 'Color', colours(end,:), 'MarkerSize', 5, 'MarkerFaceColor', colours(end,:));
```

My code. I tell cmap to make only 7 entries in the lookup table instead using its default number of colour map entries.

```
    rng = redvalue - radmin
    n_colours = 7
    localrng = rng/n_colours
    localmin = radmin - localrng
    localmax = radmin
    cmp = plt.get_cmap('jet', n_colours)
    for index in range(1,n_colours - 1):
        localmin = localmin + localrng
        localmax = localmax + localrng
        row,col = np.where(np.logical_and(rad >= localmin, rad < localmax))
        plt.pcolormesh(x1[row][col],y1[row][col],rad[row][col], cmap = cmp(index), vmin = radmin, vmax = radmax, edgecolors = 'none')
```

This is not translating into Python too well. I do not know if my indexing of the data matrix elements is working properly yet, because the immediate error is about the colormap. Is what I want even possible? Can I get an individual colours from a cmap object and feed them to pcolormesh one colour at a time?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\UserData\Documents\Stuff\tensorflow\OpenGDF2_2.py", line 199, in <module>
    PlotRad(data, 30, 50)
  File "C:\UserData\Documents\Stuff\tensorflow\OpenGDF2_2.py", line 165, in PlotRad
    plt.pcolormesh(x1[row][col],y1[row][col],rad[row][col], cmap = cmp(index), vmin = radmin, vmax = radmax, edgecolors = 'none')
  File "C:\Users\keepit20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2773, in pcolormesh
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\keepit20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\keepit20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 6002, in pcolormesh
    collection.set_cmap(cmap)
  File "C:\Users\keepit20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 342, in set_cmap
    cmap = get_cmap(cmap)
  File "C:\Users\keepit20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 182, in get_cmap
    % (name, ', '.join(sorted(cmap_d))))
ValueError: Colormap (0.0, 0.16666666666666666, 1.0, 1.0) is not recognized. Possible values are: Accent, Accent_r, Blues, Blues_r, BrBG, BrBG_r, BuGn, BuGn_r, BuPu, BuPu_r, CMRmap, CMRmap_r, Dark2, Dark2_r, GnBu, GnBu_r, Greens, Greens_r, Greys, Greys_r, OrRd, OrRd_r, Oranges, Oranges_r, PRGn, PRGn_r, Paired, Paired_r, Pastel1, Pastel1_r, Pastel2, Pastel2_r, PiYG, PiYG_r, PuBu, PuBuGn, PuBuGn_r, PuBu_r, PuOr, PuOr_r, PuRd, PuRd_r, Purples, Purples_r, RdBu, RdBu_r, RdGy, RdGy_r, RdPu, RdPu_r, RdYlBu, RdYlBu_r, RdYlGn, RdYlGn_r, Reds, Reds_r, Set1, Set1_r, Set2, Set2_r, Set3, Set3_r, Spectral, Spectral_r, Wistia, Wistia_r, YlGn, YlGnBu, YlGnBu_r, YlGn_r, YlOrBr, YlOrBr_r, YlOrRd, YlOrRd_r, afmhot, afmhot_r, autumn, autumn_r, binary, binary_r, bone, bone_r, brg, brg_r, bwr, bwr_r, cividis, cividis_r, cool, cool_r, coolwarm, coolwarm_r, copper, copper_r, cubehelix, cubehelix_r, flag, flag_r, gist_earth, gist_earth_r, gist_gray, gist_gray_r, gist_heat, gist_heat_r, gist_ncar, gist_ncar_r, gist_rainbow, gist_rainbow_r, gist_stern, gist_stern_r, gist_yarg, gist_yarg_r, gnuplot, gnuplot2, gnuplot2_r, gnuplot_r, gray, gray_r, hot, hot_r, hsv, hsv_r, inferno, inferno_r, jet, jet_r, magma, magma_r, nipy_spectral, nipy_spectral_r, ocean, ocean_r, pink, pink_r, plasma, plasma_r, prism, prism_r, rainbow, rainbow_r, seismic, seismic_r, spring, spring_r, summer, summer_r, tab10, tab10_r, tab20, tab20_r, tab20b, tab20b_r, tab20c, tab20c_r, terrain, terrain_r, twilight, twilight_r, twilight_shifted, twilight_shifted_r, viridis, viridis_r, winter, winter_r
```

SOLUTION THANKS TO JODY KLYMAK: use colors.BoundaryNorm to build a discrete boundary array. Remember to get_cmap your colormap with the same number of discrete.

```
    rng = redvalue - radmin
    n_colours = 7
    localrng = rng/n_colours
    localmin = radmin - localrng
    localmax = radmin
    cmp = plt.get_cmap('jet', n_colours)
    bounds = localmax
    bounds = np.asarray(bounds)
    for index in range(1,n_colours - 1):
        localmin = localmin + localrng
        localmax = localmax + localrng
        bounds = np.append(bounds, localmax)

    bounds = np.append(bounds, radmax)
    norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors = n_colours)
    plt.pcolormesh(x1,y1,rad, norm = norm, cmap = cmp, edgecolors = 'none')

    plt.axis([x1.min(), x1.max(), y1.min(), y1.max()])
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try a `BoundaryNorm`?  https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION THANKS TO JODY KLYMAK: use colors.BoundaryNorm to build a discrete boundary array. And remember to get_cmap your colormap with the same number of discrete intervals.

```
rng = redvalue - radmin
n_colours = 7
localrng = rng/n_colours
localmin = radmin - localrng
localmax = radmin
cmp = plt.get_cmap('jet', n_colours)
bounds = localmax
bounds = np.asarray(bounds)
for index in range(1,n_colours - 1):
    localmin = localmin + localrng
    localmax = localmax + localrng
    bounds = np.append(bounds, localmax)

bounds = np.append(bounds, radmax)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors = n_colours)
plt.pcolormesh(x1,y1,rad, norm = norm, cmap = cmp, edgecolors = 'none')

plt.axis([x1.min(), x1.max(), y1.min(), y1.max()])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```